# Sending data via onclick

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to do a really simple forum with a simple reply system. Every response of a post has an icon where you can "quote", or reply rather, a different reply of the post. I have never encountered anything similar to this to I'm pretty lost.

I have tried sending hidden post data but the values accumulate and the last hidden input value is the one sent to the page that is going to catch it.

I am using CodeIgniter.

**EDIT**: I managed to do something via javascript, I am sending the data I want, but the taget page of the post doesn't show anything when I echo the data...

Javascript:

```
function citar(key)
{
    document.getElementsByName('esta-cita').value=key;  
    document.getElementById('form-cita').submit();
}
```

Here is the code:

```
$contenido = '<a href=#'.$numRespuestas.'>#'.$numRespuestas.'</a><br>'.$row['contenido'];
$this->table->add_row($contenido);

$pie = array(
    'data' => '
        <div style="float: left">
            &#822;&nbsp; de '.$row['autor'].
            ' el '.$row['dia'].
            ' a las '.$row['hora'].'
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
            <span class="icon icon-reply cursor" onclick="citar('.$numRespuestas.')"></span>
        </div>',
    'class' => 'pag-row'
);
$this->table->add_row($pie);

$tabla .= $this->table->generate();

$numRespuestas++;
```

Comment: Don't know if i completely understood your question , but i would like to see the form_hidden() function, also i guess you should assign $numRespuestas = $numRespuestas++; and then try to send it.

Comment: I managed to send it via javascript but it seems like it is not working well, because I am echoing the post data where it's supposed to get caught and nothing happens.

Comment: Please open your application in Google Chrome, click on "inspect element" and hit network tab make AJAX call, there is all information you need.

Comment: Make AJAX call? I don't know what you want me to do.